# How do I replace a string in nth line of a huge text efficiently?

Tags: linux, performance, text-manipulation

I have a CSV file which is around 3 GB having 20 million lines. I am trying to replace a string in a line using sed but it takes around 12 minutes on my i5 processor with 4GB RAM. This is the command I am using right now.

`sed -i '27s/string1/string2/' hugetext.csv`

Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: There's only a faster way if the line you're replacing is the same length with the line you're replacing it with and you know exactly where the line is. If it's not consider using a database instead of a text document.

Comment: If both of the lines have same length, what is the faster way?

Comment: Open the file and replace bytes X to Y with the new content. May need some script to do this.